# a simple javascript with a switch statement

Tags: javascript

Im learning javascript, and I am struggling to get my case statement to work. The idea is that you enter any number between 1 - 7 in the form it will invoke a function and it will alert giving you the day of the week. The default is "not a valid day". It seems really simple but I thought I had done it right, I have a feeling its a variable problem......

```
function DayOfTheWeek()

var 1 = DayOfTheWeek;
var 2 = DayOfTheWeek;
var 3 = DayOfTheWeek;
var 4 = DayOfTheWeek;
var 5 = DayOfTheWeek;
var 6 = DayOfTheWeek;
var 7 = DayOfTheWeek;


switch (DayOfTheWeek){
case '1':
alert ("It's Monday");
break;

case 2:
alert ("It's Tuesday");
break;

case 3:
alert ("It's Wednsday");
break;

case 4:
alert ("It's Thursday");
break;

case 5:
alert ("It's Friday");
break;

case 6:
alert ("It's Saturday");
break;

case 7:
alert ("It's Sunday");
break;

default:
alert ("Not a valid day");
break;
}
```

Comment: Variables cannot start with a number. How else would the JavaScript parser distinguish a number from a variable?

Comment: Where's the rest of the function definition for `DayOfTheWeek()`, ignoring the unused (and impossible) numeric variables...

Comment: Also, you probably want to pass a parameter whose day of week you want to output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly all of your code is wrong.

Your forgot the { after the function is defined and the } at the end of the function. You want to use give a variable the same name like the function (it seems that you want to do this).

A variable name can't start with a number.

What you want could be:

```
    function DayOfTheWeek(day) {
        switch(day){
            case 1:
                alert ("It's Monday");
            break;
            case 2:
                alert ("It's Tuesday");
            break;

            case 3:
                alert ("It's Wednsday");
            break;

            case 4:
                alert ("It's Thursday");
            break;

            case 5:
                alert ("It's Friday");
            break;

            case 6:
                alert ("It's Saturday");
            break;

            case 7:
                alert ("It's Sunday");
            break;

            default:
                alert ("Not a valid day");
            break;
        }
    }
```